# Writing a program to edit PHP files through GUI

Tags: php, apache, scripting, automation, sftp

I want to write a program or script that will allow one to make simple changes to a PHP files.
There are `<div="article">` tags which are basically just some text and maybe a photo. Basically, whenever a new article is written I have to use SFTP the file over, add a new `<div="article">` with some text and SFTP it back over.

This is basically because I don't like spending my time adding articles to PHP, and would rather have the authors just enter their text, and maybe upload a picture or embed a youtube video. The authors all have read/write access to the server, so editing could be done client side as opposed to writing the code in the webpage.

What would be a good way of automating this process? I was thinking about writing a program to just SFTP the php files, edit them, and reupload them, but if someone has a better idea just let me know.

My strongest languages are C++ and Java, but I have been fiddling around with Python and Visual Basic. I would be willing to learn a new language if it greatly simplified this.

Comment: Yeah, the site looks like it's straight out of 1996. It's an internal website which has been working fine though. I can basically write this script or rewrite the whole website.

Comment: You might been looking for something like a [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_management_system)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For having users *able to add their own images/text easily* i would go for an online [wysiwyg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WYSIWYG) editor like [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com) which gives such functionality at the cost of some javascript. You can of course manage what they can *do/or do not* (plugins/buttons etc.) to avoid anything nasty..

For having users able to add their own PHP code i would go for [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/) which allows for real editing of the **majority** of scripting languages.

About the editing phase, i recommend against *download/edit/upload* again procedures. Just keep the changes in database entries **per user** and apply the ones you want after processing.
The whole thing can be programmed in a specific language but i really think that programming it in *PHP* would be a lot easier (given the support anywhere)